# Robot with four mecanum wheels, degrees of freedom and Lagrange equations for dynamic motion

Tags: dynamical-systems, lagrange-multiplier, holonomy

I have a mobile robot with four mecanum wheels with the following configuration:

[image]

I need to define a dynamic model and I was starting using the Lagrange equation to evaluate the kinetic and potential energy.

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\vartheta}_\mathrm{iw}}\right)-
\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial\vartheta_\mathrm{iw}}=\tau_i
$$

Then, in order to calculate the kinetic energy, I was using:

$$K=\frac12 m(v_x^2+v_y^2)+\frac12 J_zw_z^2+\frac12 J_w(\dot{\vartheta}_{1w}^2+\dot{\vartheta}_{2w}^2+\dot{\vartheta}_{3w}^2+\dot{\vartheta}_{4w}^2)$$

by considering all the four wheels. I found out that some researchers do not consider all the four wheels, but only three because of the limited degrees of freedom (it should be $3$ dof).

Is it correct to consider the contributions of all wheels or do I just need to consider only three wheels? Can you please explain it better to me?

Is the format of the first equation correct or do I need to add some other contribute?

Thank you.

EDIT:
This is the coordinates system that I'm using to define the model:

[image]

Comment: You have to consider the energy of all the wheels, but you can choose a coordinate system with fewer degrees of freedom. For example, if you only drive the robot forward, with the wheels in sync, you could represent it with one coordinate. For an extreme example, you could start with 30 degrees of freedom -- 6 for each body -- to express your energy. But then you could pare them down based on the constraints on the system (wheels being attached to body, etc). It's all about reduction of coordinates for the same energy.

Comment: Thank you, in my case, the robot moves in a 2D space and can move in all directions. My reference system is set up at the geometric center of the vehicle. How should I handle it in this case?

Comment: Hmm. It depends. If you can potentially slip, and the wheels have independent control, you may want to have separate coordinates for the base and wheels for that condition -- after all, the vehicle could be slipping in any direction. If you disregard slip, then you could solve for the four wheel velocities based on the base velocities, and write dynamics entirely in terms of base x, y, and angular velocity. They are probably easiest to express in a frame that's *instantaneously aligned* with the heading.

Comment: I think there are some nonholonomous constraints to consider...

Comment: Thank you! Can you please pinpoint me with some examples or papers?